# rm -r option for a long directory of nested directories

Tags: linux

I am trying to delte a long nested directory by rm -r command

```
[root@**** t***-api]# rm -r /tmp/docker_1
rm: descend into directory '/tmp/docker_1'? y
rm: descend into directory '/tmp/docker_1/bin'? y
rm: remove regular file '/tmp/docker_1/bin/sed'? y
rm: remove regular file '/tmp/docker_1/bin/setfacl'? y
rm: remove symbolic link '/tmp/docker_1/bin/sh'?
```

But it prompts so many yes and no question. Is there anyway to pass -y to all of them?

Comment: Use `rm -rf ...` The `f` option means it will do the operation without asking you for confirmation. See the [rm manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) for details, or type `man rm` at your Linux prompt.

Comment: `rm` doesn't normally do this. I suspect you have it aliased to `rm -i` to add prompting.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar that's a good point. I noticed Ubuntu in particular defaults to creating the alias when setting up a system.

Comment: Use the standard command instead of your alias: `command rm -r /tmp/docker_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm -rf /directory/to/be/deleted
```

`-f` force delete

or

```
rm -Ir /directory/to/be/deleted
```

`-I` prompt once before deleting